# Ramification of number fields and completion

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields. Take a prime $\mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$. I suspect that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is unramified over $\mathcal{O}_K$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{L_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ is étale over $\mathcal{O}_{K_{\mathfrak{p}}}$, where $L_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is the completion of $L$ at a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ occuring in the prime factorization of $\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{q}_n^{e_n}$.

Can anyone show this?

This could be interesting since It would help to understand the picture of the étale fundamental group. $\text{Gal}_{ab}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ has $p$-unramified quotient group for each prime. I suspect that, for each prime $p$, this group corresponds to the absolute galois groups of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, i.e. $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}}$. Since the absolute galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the finite adeles, this is talking about the quotient map $\prod'_{p} \mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$, where $'$ denotes a subproduct.

Comment: Do you mean $L_{\mathfrak{q}}$ completion at a prime above $\mathfrak{p}$ or something else

Comment: @reuns right, let me fix that.

Comment: The ramification of $O_{L_{\mathfrak{q}}}/O_{K_\mathfrak{p}}$ at their only prime is $e$ such that $\mathfrak{p}O_L = \mathfrak{q}^e I$ with $I$ an ideal of $O_L$ comaximal with $\mathfrak{q}$, the point is that $\mathfrak{p}$ becomes principal $=(\pi_K)$ in $(O_K-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}O_K$, same for $\mathfrak{q}$, and $(\pi_K) = (\pi_L)^e$ in $(O_L-\mathfrak{q})^{-1}O_L$ thus in its completion $\varprojlim (O_L-\mathfrak{q})^{-1}O_L/(\pi_L^n)$

Comment: @reuns sorry, but I don't understand the consequences of that immediately. It seems like that should make the extension étale, no?

Comment: $O_{L_{\mathfrak{q}}}/O_{K_\mathfrak{p}}$ etale means $e=1$

Comment: @reuns thanks so much!

Comment: Your claims about the absolute Galois group don't make sense. And $\text{Gal}_{ab}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)/\Bbb{Q})=\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times=\prod_p \Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ where $p$ is the only ramified prime of the subextension $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q})$ corresponding to the quotient $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\prod_{q\ne p} \Bbb{Z}_q^\times$, but I don't think this is immediate, this follow only from the explicit descriptions coming from Kronecker Weber and cyclotomic extensions (more generally class field theory)

Comment: @reuns. Sorry you're right.